# Angular material remove image color in mat-carousel

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am using  in my app to slide over images. it works fine but there is a grey color over every image i want to remove that and use the original images.

```
<mat-carousel timings="250ms ease-in" [autoplay]="true" interval="5000" maxWidth="100%"
   proportion="25" slides="5" [loop]="true" [hideArrows]="false" [hideIndicators]="false" [useKeyboard]="true"
   [useMouseWheel]="false" orientation="ltr">
   <mat-carousel-slide #matCarouselSlide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index" [image]="slide.image"
       overlayColor="#00000040" [hideOverlay]="false"></mat-carousel-slide>
</mat-carousel>
```

The images look like this

[image: image from app]

The original images are brighter

[image: Original image]

Any idea how to achieve this

Comment: In your mat-carousel-slide you are using `overlayColor="#00000040" [hideOverlay]="false"`. Rather you should hide overlay. Try `[hideOverlay]="true"` and remove `overlayColor`.

Comment: Thanks. I have added it in the answer section. Please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mat-carousel-slide you are using `overlayColor="#00000040" [hideOverlay]="false"`. Rather you should hide overlay. Try `[hideOverlay]="true"` and remove `overlayColor`.